# Keeping models up to date with Backbone and stickit

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-stickit

I am using backbone + stickit to give me 2 way bindings between my views and models but have come up against some issues.

**How to keep the model up to date with the server?**

I have setup my collection to call fetch() every 60 seconds.  This gets the latest version of the models from the server and 'intelligently merges' them.  But, I am still seeing local changes overwritten.  If I have entered some text in a textbox (which is correctly bound using stickit), the changes from the server overwrite the local changes.

**How to update the server when the view changes?**

Stickit emits a change event on the model when an attribute is changed, but change events are also triggered when attributes on the server have changed.  Where is the best place to call model.save() so its only called when stickit emits a change event?

Comment: How do users use your app? Do you want to support real-time collaborative editing? Could you support resource locking so that only one user can update a resource at a time? The 60 second update lag is not a good idea if multiple users can edit a piece of content.

Comment: I could update more often, but it would just put more strain on the server....

Comment: Did you get anywhere with solving this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can save model on every model `change` event (bad idea)
2. You can try to fetch model with the `silent` option and then just trigger change event on some attributes if needed (better idea)
3. Set `updateView` to `false` http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/#bindings/updateview (good idea)